# VS'08 C++ Access Violcation When Initialising Pointer Previously had no issues

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, access-violation

I'm writing a code to index the skills available to a user in a game, constructed as a linked list. I've throughly tested the function that populates the list and it seems to be working correctly (so the head pointer for the list shouldn't be null). When I attempt to traverse the list to set values in the skill, before any of the code which writes to memory within the list gets to execute the program is crashing when I initialise the temp pointer within the search function of the list to the head pointer.

What makes this additionally weird to me is that it worked fine (and I had tested this fairly thuroughly) until I added in a list to store a list of available items, and may just be missing an odd interaction between the two when I populate them.

The specific error is that the pointer is supposedly accessing memory index 0x000000c to write to, but I don't see how the code at that point is dealing with a null pointer at all (since after 10 runs of the program the OS shouldn't be allocating that block of memory to the temp pointer every time and nothing else should be null.

I'm probably just ramblind at this point so here's the code:

The function that causes the error according to the debugger:

```
void Mechanics::setSkillValue(int index, int value)
   {
    Skill *temp = FirstSkill; // << The error is happening on this line //

    while((temp != NULL)&&(temp->index != index))
    {
    temp = temp->next;
    }

    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        cout << "%";
    }
    else temp->setValue(value);

 // cout << temp->returnValue(); //This was a test check, not needed for anything
}
```

The Function that's supposed to populate the skill and item lists.

```
 void Mechanics::Populate()
 { 
 ifstream skillstream("Skills.txt");
 if(skillstream.is_open())
 {
    while(skillstream.good())
    {
        Skill *newskill;
        int indexval;
        string skillindex;
        string skillname;
        string skilldescription;

        cout << "TP4" << endl; //TEST POINT
        getline(skillstream, skillindex);
        cout << skillindex;
        getline(skillstream, skillname);
        cout << skillname;
        getline(skillstream, skilldescription);
        cout << skilldescription; cout << endl;

        indexval = atoi(skillindex.c_str());

        newskill = new Skill(skillname, skilldescription,indexval);
    //cout << "TP5" << endl; //TEST POINT
    if(newskill == NULL) cout << "NULL!!!";
    addSkill(newskill);
    }
}

ifstream itemstream("Items.txt");
if(itemstream.is_open())
{
    while(itemstream.good())
    {
        Item *newitem;
        int indexval;
        string skillindex;
        string skillname;
        string skilldescription;
        string abilitydescription;
        string valueSTR;
        string typeSTR;
        int value;
        int type;
        int numeric[5];
//          cout << "TP4" << endl; //TEST POINT
        getline(itemstream, skillindex);
//          cout << skillindex;
        getline(itemstream, skillname);
//      cout << skillname;
        getline(itemstream, skilldescription);
//      cout << skilldescription;
        getline(itemstream, abilitydescription);
        getline(itemstream, valueSTR);
        value = atoi(valueSTR.c_str());
        getline(itemstream,typeSTR);
        type = atoi(typeSTR.c_str());

        for (int i=0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            string numericSTR;
            getline(itemstream,numericSTR);
            numeric[i]=atoi(numericSTR.c_str());
        }


        indexval = atoi(skillindex.c_str());

        newitem = new Item(indexval, skilldescription, skillname, abilitydescription, value, type, numeric);
    //cout << "TP5" << endl; //TEST POINT
//  if(newskill == NULL) cout << "NULL!!!";
    addItem(newitem);
    }
}
```

The function that's supposed to actually add a skill to the skill list:

```
void Mechanics::addSkill(Skill *nskill)
{
 Skill *temp = FirstSkill;

 if(FirstSkill == NULL)
 {
     FirstSkill = nskill;
     //cout << "TP1" << endl; //TEST POINT
       //FirstSkill->printname();
 }

 else
 {
    while((temp->next != NULL))
    {
    temp = temp-> next;
    //cout << "TP2" << endl; //TEST POINT
    //temp->printname(); cout << endl;
    }
     if (FirstSkill != NULL)
     {
         temp->next = nskill;
         nskill->next = NULL;
     }
 }
}
```

The code that I have is somewhat extensive so I'm only going to include the blocks which are potentially interacting with the function that's throwing up the error.

Thanks in advance for reading through this, and any assistance you're able to offfer, I've been banging my head against this for about 6 hours now and I've lost the perspective to actually track this one down.

Comment: Too more code... And where is declaration/ first initizaliation of FirstSkill?

Comment: Where is `setSkillValue` being called?  Might you be calling the method on a null pointer?  That would explain why accessing an object member would trigger the access violation.  (This is undefined behavior, but most compilers will emit code that can cope with a null object pointer when invoking a non-virtual method.)

Comment: setSkillVlaue doesn't take in a pointer as an argument; it takes in the index of the skill I'm looking for and starts at FirstSkill. FirstSkill is a pointer to a Skill declared in the Mechanics header file as a private pointer.

Comment: I notice a couple things.  One, are you sure that you are initializing FirstSkill to NULL before checking `temp != NULL && temp->index != index` because if you never initialize FirstSkill, it would have undefined behavior since you don't know what the contents of that block of memory are.  Possibly on your old compiler, it automagically did it.  
Secondly, in addSkill, you have `if(FirstSkill == NULL) {}else{ if(FirstSkill != NULL)` which is kind of redundant. makes me wonder if something oddball is going on here as well.